# Run cronjob for all but a 30 hour consecutive period per week

Tags: php, cron

From  4pm est on Friday till Saturday 10pm est, no emails should send out using a cronjob. How can I setup my cronjob to do this?

Comment: What is your current cronjob schedule?

Comment: Why not let the script that gets called deal with stuff like this?

Comment: @Pekka - I was just thinking the same thing...

Comment: I set the cronjob file which is running all the day  in every 1 hr. Client wants to stop the mail on the particular days only.

Comment: @lifeline still - why not handle this in the script? I don't think crontab's syntax is flexible enough for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the PHP file, you could add this to the top:

**EDIT**

Note, I was using the wrong 24-hour clock character, it should be `H`. See [this codepad](http://codepad.org/TM5pMFV2).

```
<?php

$wH = date('wH');

if (($wH > 516 && $wH < 525) || ($wH > 600 && $wH < 622)) {
    exit('Script exited.');
}

echo 'Script ran.';

?>
```

http://codepad.org/uKzlJjzs

This simply creates a numeric representation of the day of the week with the hour and tests to make sure the time is not between these values, exiting the script if it is.

Comment: @lifeline - See my edit, I had the wrong 24-hour clock character.

Comment: Ya its working. Today is saturday. It stopped running. Please confirm it will be stopped upto Saturday 10pm  ?